# Apache2 redirect to another domain with ssl

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I have a no clue why this fails. I just want to redirect all domain to `www.maindomain.com` and also `http` to `https`, what am i missing?

```
# redirect http to https    
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# redirect without www to www
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^maindomain.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.maindomain.com  [r=301,nc]

# redirect another domain to www.maindomain.com    
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off # this i was missing 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?anotherdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.maindomain.com [R=301,L]
```

1. `http://maindomain.com` to `https:/www.maindomain.com/` works
2. `http://anotherdomain.com` to `https:/www.maindomain.com/` works
3. `https://anotherdomain.com` to `https:/www.maindomain.com/` fails

Comment: strange, the comment with the RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off, hint was right its now working, but the answer has been deleted, just as i wanted to accept it, i was missing a 2nd RewriteCond in the 3rd redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Http to Https redirection for Another domain failed because Your Rule is missing the following line :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
```

Try :

```
# redirect another domain to www.maindomain.com    

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?anotherdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.maindomain.com [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Just copy and paste the above code in .htaccess file then the whole website will be redirected to “https” when the browser is opened in “http” mode. The browser just get redirected using url rewriting in .htaccess.